# Wi-Fi connection stop to work after few seconds connected

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I recently sign plan of Vodafone Wi-Fi with a Fon pass account to get internet. Vodafone is the operator of this service and Fon is the company behind the scene.

The problem is that after few seconds the connection stops to work and I need authenticate on the service again, again and again...

I'm using Debian Stretch and my Wi-Fi connection always works fine on other places. I discarded hardware and firmware problems. I have other devices that occurs the same problem, not only my computer.

I already tried to find anything on the internet searching services but without success. That's why I'm questing here.

On my searches I knew that the modems use the OpenWrt based OS.

**The questions are:**

- Anyone already use this service, what is our opinion?
- There is place to see the log of Wi-Fi events on my system?
- Can be a router problem that I'm connecting? If yes, there is a way to test it?

**Helpful links:**

- https://fon.com/faq/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fon_(company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly answering your questions directly.

- I have not (grid-wifi topology like that's pretty rare in the States outside office/public buildings). But grid-wifi has its own difficulties above and beyond conventional wifi such as shared bandwidth and possibly spotty deployment of nodes in the grid.
- Yes, in /var/log/syslog. Try `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal window. That should allow you to watch the syslog in real-time as you attempt to connect. Be aware syslog logs everything except auth related events to that log file. So not everything in there has to do with wifi. But the Wifi related stuff should involve NetworkManager and wpa-supplicant. You may need to elevate to root via `su` or `sudo` to access log files, not sure with Debian. If `/var/log/syslog` is too spammy to read try `/var/log/messages` instead.
- Eh... "Router" is a complex term here. Generally speaking the nearest router on their nework is a long way off. The device you are actually connecting to is just an group on nearby access points. It could be a problem with the access points you are connecting to or, if their grid topology is poorly planned, it could be an access point between you and the nearest router. If you have some sort of base station in your home/office that does the actual connecting to their network then that would likely be a router (or, perhaps, just a repeater)... but from what I read on their site they don't offer that.

What I would check first is to be completely sure you have the correct authentication information (username/password/wpa key). The description of your problem sounds very much like an authentication issue.

Second, it's possible your devices simply can't reach the access point. What you have to remember is that just cause the AP can transmit clearly to you doesn't mean your devices can transmit clearly back. And the signal strength shown by NetworkManager, in addition to being arbitrary and quite meaningless regardless, is also only an indication of the strength of the signal from the AP. Grid access points are often configured to disconnect any device unable to transmit with a certain minimum signal strength to the AP. The idea being that the device will reconnect to a closer AP... which there may not be one.

If any of your devices are portable and you think you know where one of the access points are you could try going and standing under it to see if that solves the problem. If that's the case you may consider installing a wifi repeater in your home/office with an exterior, directional antenna pointed at the nearest grid AP.

Third, because you use Debian, it's quite likely your version of wpa-supplicant is very out of date. You may need to download the source for a newer version and compile it (and possibly NetworkManager) yourself. Being that you use Debian and this sounds like an authentication issue, that's actually a pretty likely culprit barring bad authentication details.

Also, you may need to compile and update your wiki kernel modules as well. That said, it's just as likely fully functioning wifi drivers for your adapter don't exist for Linux. No matter what anyone tells you, Linux hardware support... at least for printers, wifi, and input peripherals... is extremely inconsistent and spotty.